# error while deploying ejb2.0 on weblogic server 12c

Tags: weblogic, ejb-2.x, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy the ejb2.0 on weblogic server 12c. 
While deploying the ejb2.0 it doesn't give me any error but later while doing the lookup it throws exception.

javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.naming.LinkException: [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'ejb.MyManager'. Resolved 'ejb'; remaining name 'MyManager']; Link Remaining Name: 'ejb/MyManager'

this comes at getContext().lookup(name);
any clue why it comes and why it the time of ejb deployment its not showing up?

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

If deployment went well you should be able to find the beans in the jndi tree in the admin console. Did you try this? Are the names as you expect?